# Return a float list from a stored list

Tags: python

> Write a function which gets numbers from the user (use this command to get the digits from the user: input('Enter the digit\n'). Note that \n is used to go to the next line), and stores them in a list, and ultimately returns it.
>
> If the user enters a non-digit character, ignore it, unless they write 'Stop' in which case you should terminate the function and return the outcome in the form of a list.
>
> You can use the method var.isdigit() to check if the variable var is a digit or not.

```
def num_print():
    output_list = []
    while True:
        var=input('Enter the digit\n')
        
        if var.isdigit():
            user_list = var.split()
            output_list += user_list
        
        elif var == 'Stop':
           
            for i in range(len(output_list)):
                output_list[i] = float(output_list[i])
                return output_list
                break
```

I expect at last when a person enters Stop, it gives, let's say, `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]` if inputs were maybe `1, 2, 3, 4,h, 5, Stop`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `return` after the whole for loop runs otherwise your loop will end on the first iteration and you'll only get the first number as a float and the rest as a string. You can also remove the `break` as `return` already stops the loop by getting out of the function.

```
elif var == 'Stop':
    for i in range(len(output_list)):
        output_list[i] = float(output_list[i])
    return output_list
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
output_list = list(map(float, output_list))
```

your mistake:

```
return output_list
```

after first convertion str to float

your correct code:

```
for i in range(len(output_list)):
    output_list[i] = float(output_list[i])
return output_list
```